# failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Whenever I import tensorflow in my code, I get the following warning

```
2021-07-03 20:43:38.432690: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

To check gpu availability I ran

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

For which it returned `[]`

I also ran

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Which returned some noticeable things

```
2021-07-03 20:49:02.552671: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

2021-07-03 20:49:02.584748: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2394575000 Hz

2021-07-03 20:49:02.585433: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f32e8000b60 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:

2021-07-03 20:49:02.585504: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version

2021-07-03 20:49:02.590168: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1

2021-07-03 20:49:02.737950: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

2021-07-03 20:49:02.737996: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (user_name-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
False
```

Following are my setup specifications

```
Python 3.8.5
TensorFlow 2.2.0
nvcc 10.1
os Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
GPU GM108M [GeForce 830M]
```

What should I do to resolve this? I want tensorflow lib. to utilise the local GPU while running the code.

EDIT: libcudart,libcuda are installed.

Comment: You either don't have a CUDA capable GPU in that system, or your GPU driver (and CUDA) are not properly installed to be able to use it.

Comment: Which GPU do you have?

Comment: And more importantly, what is the question here?

Comment: The problem is that you do not seem to be running the Nvidia graphics drivers (not the same as CUDA). You need to install the official nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dr. Snoopy mentioned, Nvidia graphics drivers were missing. I installed them using link,
https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

I also installed, CuDNN from
https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive

Now, when I type

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I get

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0',device_type='GPU')]
```