# Tensorflow not detecting CUDA device

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am having some issues with Tensorflow, that seems not to detect my GPU.

When running some code using Tensorflow, I get the **error**:

tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:328]

failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Here's my **config**:

- Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080 Ti
- Ubuntu 18.04
- CUDA 11.4, driver 470.57.02
- Tensorflow 2.5

My GPU is well detected (checked it with `nvidia-smi`) and `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`  returns True.
I tried downgrading the CUDA version and the driver but nothing changed.

Does anybody has some hints on how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think Tensorflow2.x is not prebuilt for CUDA >=10.2. You can build it from the source. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237724/failed-call-to-cuinit-cuda-error-no-device-no-cuda-capable-device-is-detected

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install a package built with the same CUDA environment to ensure compatibility. `Tensorflow 2.5` is compatible with `CUDA 11.2`.

Take a look at [Tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)

Answer (score 1):

The issue occurs due to TensorFlow 2.5 is compatible with. So, just downgrade (re-install) your CUDA to 11.2.
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.2.0-download-archive